Routing traffic to docker container from specific source IP
I am currently facing problems with routing traffic from outside to a docker container.
This is my setup:

Rocky Linux 9.4 host
Docker network (bridge) with IP range 172.20.0.0/16
3 docker containers (running Rapid7 scan engine, but that's not important), each has a service available on port 40814, but those are not exported, also each server has a static IP (172.20.0.2-4) on that docker network
firewalld configuration on host:

public (active)
 target: default
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: ens192
 sources:
 services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
 ports: 10050/tcp 40814/tcp
 protocols:
 forward: yes
 masquerade: yes
 forward-ports:
   port=40814:proto=tcp:toport=40814:toaddr=172.20.0.2
 source-ports:
 icmp-blocks:
 rich rules:

What I'm trying to achieve is that based on a given source IP (other server on my network) I would like to route traffic to one of the 3 docker containers.
The other server knows only IP of my rocky linux server and port 40814, then the rocky linux server decides to which docker to route the traffic. This is not an attempt at loadbalancing.
I'm able to check that the docker container is working correctly by telnet 172.20.0.2 40814 (from host/rocky linux server) which then shows connection attempts in docker container logs, but when I try to do telnet 10.0.20.123 40814 (ip of rocky linux server) from other servers on my network, I only get Trying 10.0.20.123.... Trying any other port on that IP immediately ends in Connection refused. Logs are also not reporting connection attempts.
I've tried different firewall setups like this:
One:
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule 
family="ipv4" \
source address="10.0.20.120/32" \
port protocol="tcp" port="40814" accept'
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=40814:proto=tcp:toport=40814:toaddr=172.20.0.2
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=41814:proto=tcp:toaddr=172.20.0.2:toport=40814 --permanent 

Two:
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule 
family="ipv4" \
source address="10.0.20.120/32" \
forward-port protocol="tcp" port="41814" toport=40814 toaddr=172.20.0.2'

SELinux is Enforcing, but I'm not sure that makes a difference.
Can you help? Many thanks!
Edit: adding some more info
network related docker info:
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "06e60f163d002b1ef377542172f4007dcfa33749bf104315047921ac8af0d8c0",
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/06e60f163d00",
            "Ports": {},
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "se-net": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "nse-1",
                        "nse-1"
                    ],
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "NetworkID": "ae57f90864d9171ee342803f1ce2d336db530482f000e8a7c2c4ef44fb9f09b9",
                    "EndpointID": "9f12ea7fca0ce272d3cfcd4797a4d68d88c9542d2b2ce7616581a0f2aff32f90",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "nse-1",
                        "7ee892f16d9f"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Fri Jul 26 10:56:54 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [822:49320]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-ae57f90864d9 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-ae57f90864d9 ! -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ae57f90864d9 -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-ae57f90864d9 ! -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 26 10:56:54 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Fri Jul 26 10:56:54 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [434998:26094074]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [62817:4380590]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [62817:4380590]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-ae57f90864d9 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-ae57f90864d9 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 26 10:56:54 2024

nft list ruleset
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 172.20.0.0/16 oifname != "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 15 bytes 900 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 433464 bytes 26008040 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }
}
# Warning: table ip filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" oifname != "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 15 bytes 900 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 20043 bytes 21105956 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 6609 bytes 387973 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 821 bytes 49260 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 821 bytes 49260 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" oifname != "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 15 bytes 900 accept
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 870 bytes 52200 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 20043 bytes 21105956 return
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain DOCKER {
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" oifname != "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }
}
table inet firewalld {
    chain mangle_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle + 10; policy accept;
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" goto mangle_PRE_docker
        iifname "docker0" goto mangle_PRE_docker
        iifname "ens192" goto mangle_PRE_public
        goto mangle_PRE_public
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" goto nat_PRE_docker
        iifname "docker0" goto nat_PRE_docker
        iifname "ens192" goto nat_PRE_public
        goto nat_PRE_public
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        oifname { "docker0", "br-ae57f90864d9" } jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES {
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" goto nat_POST_docker
        oifname "docker0" goto nat_POST_docker
        oifname "ens192" goto nat_POST_public
        goto nat_POST_public
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain nat_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        icmpv6 type { nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit } accept
        meta nfproto ipv6 fib saddr . mark . iif oif missing drop
    }

    chain filter_INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state invalid drop
        jump filter_INPUT_ZONES
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state invalid drop
        ip6 daddr { ::/96, ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96, 2002::/24, 2002:a00::/24, 2002:7f00::/24, 2002:a9fe::/32, 2002:ac10::/28, 2002:c0a8::/32, 2002:e000::/19 } reject with icmpv6 addr-unreachable
        jump filter_FORWARD_ZONES
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        oifname "lo" accept
        ip6 daddr { ::/96, ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96, 2002::/24, 2002:a00::/24, 2002:7f00::/24, 2002:a9fe::/32, 2002:ac10::/28, 2002:c0a8::/32, 2002:e000::/19 } reject with icmpv6 addr-unreachable
        jump filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_ZONES {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" goto filter_IN_docker
        iifname "docker0" goto filter_IN_docker
        iifname "ens192" goto filter_IN_public
        goto filter_IN_public
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre {
        oifname { "docker0", "br-ae57f90864d9" } jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_ZONES {
        iifname "br-ae57f90864d9" goto filter_FWD_docker
        iifname "docker0" goto filter_FWD_docker
        iifname "ens192" goto filter_FWD_public
        goto filter_FWD_public
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_pre {
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_public {
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_IN_public_pre
        jump filter_IN_public_log
        jump filter_IN_public_deny
        jump filter_IN_public_allow
        jump filter_IN_public_post
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post
        meta l4proto { icmp, ipv6-icmp } accept
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_allow {
        tcp dport 22 accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/64 udp dport 546 accept
        tcp dport 9090 accept
        tcp dport 10050 accept
        tcp dport 40814 accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_post {
    }

    chain nat_POST_public {
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_POST_public_pre
        jump nat_POST_public_log
        jump nat_POST_public_deny
        jump nat_POST_public_allow
        jump nat_POST_public_post
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_POST_public_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POST_public_log {
    }

    chain nat_POST_public_deny {
    }

    chain nat_POST_public_allow {
        meta nfproto ipv4 oifname != "lo" masquerade
    }

    chain nat_POST_public_post {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public {
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_FWD_public_pre
        jump filter_FWD_public_log
        jump filter_FWD_public_deny
        jump filter_FWD_public_allow
        jump filter_FWD_public_post
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post
        reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public_log {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public_deny {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public_allow {
        oifname "ens192" accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_public_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public {
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_PRE_public_pre
        jump nat_PRE_public_log
        jump nat_PRE_public_deny
        jump nat_PRE_public_allow
        jump nat_PRE_public_post
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public_allow {
        ip saddr 10.0.20.120 tcp dport 40814 dnat ip to 172.17.0.2:40814
        ip saddr 10.0.20.120 tcp dport 40814 dnat ip to 172.20.0.2:40814
    }

    chain nat_PRE_public_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public {
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_public_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_public_log
        jump mangle_PRE_public_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_public_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_public_post
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_public_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit accept
        icmpv6 type nd-router-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-redirect accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6_post {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker {
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_IN_docker_pre
        jump filter_IN_docker_log
        jump filter_IN_docker_deny
        jump filter_IN_docker_allow
        jump filter_IN_docker_post
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_post
        accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_pre {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_log {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_deny {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_allow {
    }

    chain filter_IN_docker_post {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker {
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_POST_docker_pre
        jump nat_POST_docker_log
        jump nat_POST_docker_deny
        jump nat_POST_docker_allow
        jump nat_POST_docker_post
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_log {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_deny {
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_allow {
        meta nfproto ipv4 oifname != "lo" masquerade
    }

    chain nat_POST_docker_post {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker {
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_FWD_docker_pre
        jump filter_FWD_docker_log
        jump filter_FWD_docker_deny
        jump filter_FWD_docker_allow
        jump filter_FWD_docker_post
        jump filter_FORWARD_POLICIES_post
        accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_log {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_deny {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_allow {
        oifname "docker0" accept
        oifname "br-ae57f90864d9" accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_docker_post {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker {
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump nat_PRE_docker_pre
        jump nat_PRE_docker_log
        jump nat_PRE_docker_deny
        jump nat_PRE_docker_allow
        jump nat_PRE_docker_post
        jump nat_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_pre {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_log {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_deny {
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_allow {
        ip saddr 10.0.20.120 tcp dport 40814 dnat ip to 172.20.0.2:40814
    }

    chain nat_PRE_docker_post {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker {
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_pre
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_log
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_deny
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_allow
        jump mangle_PRE_docker_post
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_pre {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_log {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_deny {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_allow {
    }

    chain mangle_PRE_docker_post {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding {
        jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_pre
        jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_log
        jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_deny
        jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_allow
        jump filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_post
        accept
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_pre {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_log {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_deny {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_allow {
    }

    chain filter_FWD_policy_docker-forwarding_post {
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding {
        jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_pre
        jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_log
        jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_deny
        jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_allow
        jump nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_post
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_pre {
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_log {
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_deny {
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_allow {
    }

    chain nat_POST_policy_docker-forwarding_post {
    }
}

firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

docker (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br-ae57f90864d9 docker0
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.0.20.120/32" forward-port port="40814" protocol="tcp" to-port="40814" to-addr="172.20.0.2"

drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

nm-shared
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcp dns ssh
  ports:
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule priority="32767" reject

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 10050/tcp 40814/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.0.20.120" forward-port port="40814" protocol="tcp" to-port="40814" to-addr="172.20.0.2"
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.0.20.120" forward-port port="40814" protocol="tcp" to-port="40814" to-addr="172.17.0.2"

trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


@TomYan thanks for the reply, didn't work, so I added output of said commands and some more :)

Thanks! You are a life saver! Connection now works, back to troubleshooting what caused it. About the typo - I noticed it and changed the rule accordingly :).

Okay so I restarted the server and the policy drop disappeared. I must have somehow added it without knowing...
Thanks again!

@TomYan would you like me to accept your solution? I guess for that you have to write an answer normally and not in comments.

I just moved my comments into an answer. Thanks!

The command you need would be:
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=10.0.20.120 forward-port protocol=tcp port=40814 to-port=40814 to-addr=172.17.0.2

(Note that this rule may have unexpected "side effect" if the host is expected to route certain traffics to some other host / container, i.e., when the (original) destination IP is not one of its own IP; in other words when destination NAT / forward-port is probably not expected to take effect. You may want to e.g. add destination address=10.0.20.123 to the rule to limit the "scope" of the rule.)
However, the problem is you have a filter table that has a hook forward chain with policy being drop. The table is NOT generated by firewalld but something else that mess with firewalling via iptables(-nft). I am not entirely sure if that's docker. (With the latest version on Arch, it does not make the policy of that chain drop.)
You can either run:
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

or insert a rule to the chain that would make the table let the traffics pass through. For example:
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.20.120 -d 172.17.0.2 -p tcp --dport 40814 -j ACCEPT

However, if it isn't just some "leftover" (for which the easiest way to confirm is obviously reboot and see), you'll need to find out what did it and then see what's the best way to "fix" it persistently. To confirm whether it's docker, try disable the docker service and reboot, check :FORWARD under *filter in iptables-save, then start the docker service and check again and see if it changes from ACCEPT to DROP. (Actually maybe you could even just restart the docker service/daemon after running iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT. Probably no reboot needed.)

Hi, this solved my issue! Thank you very much.

Today I observed the same behavior - installed fresh rocky linux 9.5 server, added said rich rules, enabled forwading with sysctl, enabled masquerade and saved this firewall config as permanent. I again had the same problem with hook forward policy drop. Will try rebooting if it will help.

Restarting helped... could this be a bug in firewall-cmd?
